# Unable to get Azure monitoring data using rest request

Tags: azure, cloud, monitoring, azure-monitoring

I am trying to integrate azure metrics with my dashboard application(web app) for live monitoring using api request.I tried with alert rules but no response coming.

this sample request i made:

```
url:https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX/resourceGroups/pwcdfp/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/test?api-version=2016-03-01
```

payload:

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/b3728f4e-cba5-44e2-bf02-b03e7fd1d94e/resourceGroups/pwcdfp/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/test",
    "name": "test",
    "type": "Microsoft.Insights/alertRules",
    "location": "southeastasia",
    "tags": {
        "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Common.Storage.CasePreservedDictionary, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Common.Storage",
        "hidden-link:/subscriptions/b3728f4e-cba5-44e2-bf02-b03e7fd1d94e/resourceGroups/pwcdfp/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/pwcdfp": "Resource"
    },
    "properties": {
        "name": "test",
        "description": "test",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "condition": {
            "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
            "dataSource": {
                "$type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.RuleMetricDataSource, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Mon.Client",
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
                "resourceUri": "/subscriptions/b3728f4e-cba5-44e2-bf02-b03e7fd1d94e/resourceGroups/pwcdfp/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/pwcdfp",
                "metricName": "Disk Read Bytes/sec"
            },
            "threshold": 1,
            "windowSize": "PT5M",
            "timeAggregation": "Average"
        },
        "lastUpdatedTime": "2016-09-19T05:34:38.6351894Z",
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
        "actions": []
    }
}

content type: application/json
Authorization token:

SharedAccessSignature uid=57d95d630ac0d2007b030003&ex=2016-09-17T09:10:00.0000000Z&sn=F3s+t2ufw76Bmh9SuoYYnF4zek0v/2jz7NXbLYssk1vwnMhcAeNxLwiA1Sg2Q5aEiQw/yPPYrmVNJbaiJOC61g==
```

Comment: sorry the request url will be : https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b3728f4e-cba5-44e2-bf02-b03e7fd1d94e/resourceGroups/pwcdfp/providers/microsoft.insights/alertrules/test?api-version=2016-03-01

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, since you first ask how to get Azure monitoring data, but then describe an alert, which is an action taken based off of monitoring data. If you're attempting to regularly get metric data from a Classic Compute VM, an alert is not the right way to do that. An alert only fires when a specific threshold is met. Instead, you can use the [.NET SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn802153.aspx) to get that data.

Not all resources provide metrics using this SDK today. For a Classic Compute VM in particular, you will not receive any metrics unless you have turned on Azure Diagnostics. You can do this by navigating to the blade in the Azure portal for the VM, going to "Diagnostics" and checking "Basic metrics."